# .htaccess - The variable %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} is not supported

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently working on an AngularJS project, and for SEO I decided to use an automatic crawler.
The only thing is that they ask to add those few lines to the **.htaccess**, resulting in a 500 Internal Server Error on my server...

```bsh
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*googlebot.* [OR][NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*bingbot.* [NC]
    RewriteRule .* http://crawlr.wombit.se/Crawler/htmlsnapshot?url=$1 [P]
</ifmodule>
```

I [tested those lines](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) against my website and the answer is:
*This variable is not supported: %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}*

I already checked a bunch of topics to see if I could find a solution, but I didn't find anything working for my case...

PS: I also tried to remove all the other rules, but I am sure that those 2 rewriteCond are throwing the error.

### Update - server configuration

Apache version  2.2.26
PHP version 5.4.26
MySQL version   5.1.73-cll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're getting that error, `%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}` is a valid apache 2.* mod_rewrite variable. The problem that I see is that your flags are messed up.

```
[OR][NC]
```

needs to be

```
[OR,NC]
```

Also, you're backreferencing using `$1`, but you've not created a grouping in your pattern, so `$1` will simply be blank, so you probably want to replace `$1` with `%{REQUEST_URI}` or create a grouping in your pattern by changing it to `(.*)`.

Comment: adding the parenthesis did the trick... However, the htaccess sample was provided by the HTML snapshot service website...  
Thank you!